# Qt Target with special characters

Tags: macos, qt, unix, qmake, info.plist

I have a QT application and right know I need to change the app name to something like **"A&B".**

I have tried to change the **TARGET** in my **.pro** file, but I am having problems with the "**&**" character in **macOS**.

I have also tried to use qmake functions like **val_escape**, **system_quote**, **shell_quote** but nothing worked for me.

As a last resource, I have tried to change the **CFBundleName** in my .plist file, which worked for app menus and etc, but not for the app name (still having problems with &, as **make** is considering the app to be called **B.app** instead of **A&B.app**

Do you know any other way to get this problem fixed? Is there even a way to have a macOS application with a name like **A&B.app**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Such special character as an _Application Name_ seems not a good idea .. you are already in trouble with it, isn't it ? do not put yourself in more trouble and use _simple_ names, ... if you have a killer reason on MacOS, use a link to your app

Comment: If a client asks that name from you, you have not so much options... -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding a DisplayName to my configuration and changing the applicationDisplayName in the Info.plist.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Exactly: the name of the app bundle and the name of the application are the same only by default. Finder does read the bundle and displays a name based on it.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you are following the right approach. What the client want is perhaps change the "user visible" strings for the application name to "A&B" - for that you need to check out the following functions in `QCoreApplication`:

```
applicationName : QString
applicationVersion : QString
organizationDomain : QString
```

Comment: I am already setting that up. But for example when you want to install the app and you open the dmg, I want the .app to be called A&B.app. The same thing when I have the app in the Applications folder. The app must be called A&B there too. After I open the app, I have no problems. Changing the bundle name in the info.plist works for me, all the strings have the right name when using the application. The problem is really the .app name itself.