# Qt qmake TARGET value with special characters

Tags: qt, target, qmake, application-name

How can I name output executable in qmake, with local characters like ä or ź. Every time I put a TARGET value with special characters, Qt throwing an error:

```
No rule to make target 'xxx.rc', needed by 'xxx.o'. Stop.

ex. TARGET = "genügen" or TARGET = "Obciążeń"
```

Comment: Related question but for MacOS : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50109920/qt-target-with-special-characters